# Having trouble starting/restarting httpd (apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I rebooted my server and now the httpd will not restart.

I tried using the command "service httpd start" but get this in response

```
[root@mail ~]# sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8888
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8888
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I am logged in as root.  I have no directory in my ect directory called  conf to find  conf/httpd.conf nor do I have init.d/apache2 in my ect directory.  I looked at my ect/init.d file but see nothing about ports.

I have a lot to learn but in the meantime I need to get this back up and running. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something is already bound port 8888. Running "netstat -tulpn | grep :8888" should tell you the name of process using the port.

Comment: [root@mail ~]# netstat -tulpn | grep :8888
[root@mail ~]#
I get nothing :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the error properly. It's not a bound port problem, it's an SELinux problem. Solution detailed in answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've most likely got [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) enabled and in "enforcing" mode.

You can disable it with:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

You can then start apache as normal with

```
sudo service httpd start
```

If you want to disable SELinux permanently, edit `/etc/selinux/config` and change `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=disabled`

If you want to continue using SELinux, you'll need to fix your config by adding access to the port, with something along the lines of

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8888
```

Comment: This is on the right track.  I did this right before you answered and can now get httpd to start. However, apachectl -k restart just returns a new line and nothing else.